# How the window function works in STFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft, wavelet, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

Can anyone experienced in signal processing and `STFT` explains to me why the window function in the below posted image is from (t-t'), given that t is the total time and t' is the width of the window?

I can not figure it out because, initially, the window is located at t=0, and if the window length for an example is 3, then the window will spans from t=0 -> t=3, and if the total time T = 10 for an example then the window function will be like `w(T-3)`, which is 7?! I really can not understand it and I believe there is any hidden thing I can not comprehend.

Kindly please clarify it and guide. Thanks
**Image**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

note that, the width of the winow function is constant throughout the entire STFT process. and the time (t) in the function g(t-t') indicate sthat, t: is the current time on the time axis and it is variable each time the window is moved/shifted to the righ to overlap the main signal.

in other words, and i hope this clarifies better, the "t" at the end of the time axis is NOT the "t" in the function g(t-t'). as i stated earlir in the function g(t-t'), t: is the current time on the time axis and it is variable for each shift of the window function and t': is the width of the window and it is constant throughout the entire STFT process.

Answer (score 0):

- `t` is your time variable, not the total time.
- `t'` is not the width of the window, it is the integration variable in the integral, and the integral is missing a `dt'` at the right end.
- `g(x)` is the window function, and the width of it is not defined above, but represented as the width of the light blue bell in the figure.

The image may have a different interpretation, but it may be wrong; if you apply these adjustments:

- Swap the labels `t` and `t'` on the horizontal axis.
- Change `x(t)` with `x(t')` on the vertical axis.

you are now looking at `x(t')` (black line) and at `g(t-t')` (upper contour of the light-blue zone) for a FIXED time `t`. The bell-shaped window function is centered around `t`, and the product of the bell and of the signal is the function of which you are calculating the Fourier transform in the equation, and it is non-zero only in proximity of the fixed value of `t`. Consistently, the quantity is the 'local', i.e. short-time, Fourier transform of the signal, in the vicinity of the fixed time `t`.

You can do the same for all values of `t` (with a different figure for each value, with a bell shifted to the left/right), and obtain the STFT.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now can i consider t is the width of the bell-shaped window function? if not what is the width of the window function?

Comment: no you can't, t is just a variable. You are the one to choose the window function and its length. For example, you could choose a [Hann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window) window, with `N=100` samples.